# How to STOP dependencies updates when editing drivers via python?

Tags: python, drivers, shape-keys

I' swapping a bunch of drivers in shape keys via python in Blender 2.8x, but I'm not liking the performance because it keeps causing dependencies updates at inconvenient moments.

At some point of the code I have this inside a loop creating a driver based on previously stored driver properties:

```
"""
Sorry for the abridged code, because it's intertwined with other functions it'd take a lot of clean up
to make it work as a stand-alone

data_shkeys is a previously defined bpy.data.shape_keys[id_data] var
get_data_path() outputs correct data_path for a given key
driver_var_clone() adds a var through variables.new() and formats it with arg2 properties
"""

# Add new driver to target shape key
d_copy = data_shkeys.driver_add(get_data_path(target_key.name))

# Replace with props from original driver
d_copy.driver.type = drivers["type"] # triggers d. update
d_copy.driver.expression = drivers["expression"] # triggers d. update
d_copy.driver.use_self = drivers_storage["use_self"]

# Dump vars from original driver
for v in drivers["vars"]: # triggers d. update
    driver_var_clone(v, d_copy.driver)
```

Changing the **expression**, driver **type** or **vars** triggers dependencies updates. Given that I'm editing multiple drivers at a time I'd like to trigger it just once, only *after* I'm done editing all of them. Is this possible?

I noticed that `bpy.ops.anim.copy_driver_button()` and `bpy.ops.anim.paste_driver_button()` surprisingly don't suffer with same performance slowdown, so if there's a way to make them work in python it would also solve my issue. I don't care whether I'm using ops or low-level api, I just want the best performance possible.